# How to Show html response in web in android with retrofit

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit

I connect to server with retrofit and one api has html response that is web page and want show this html in web to user in android.How can I do???
Please help,thank you

Comment: take data as ResponseBody and then you can get the response.body() as string. Just load that data in web view. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

In order to load a webpage (or) webpage structure (HTML,...) you can use WebView in android.

In order to load a simple URL you can use the `loadUrl` method in WebView

E.g : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-use-webview-in-android/

As your case if you got html response from retrofit and need to show the page using WebView, you can use `response.body()` to convert to string first then use the `loadData()` method in WebView to render the content.

E.g :

```
String htmlData = "Your HTML data";

WebView webview = (WebView)this.findViewById(R.id.webview);
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webview.loadData(htmlData, "text/html; charset=utf-8", "UTF-8");
```

Doc : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView#loadData(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)